# Trying to make a seprate class for my picture but the picture doesn't show up?

Tags: java, image, class, jframe, frame

I should have two images in my frame, a boy and a rock, and I want them to have seperate classes so I can do different things to each one. I asked if I should and it was recomended. I just moved my rock to a different class but now the rock doesnt show up anymore. Where's my issue?

First class:

```
       import java.awt.Color;
       import java.awt.Dimension;

       import javax.swing.*;
       public class JumpyBoy {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Boy");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

    frame.setPreferredSize (new Dimension (1000, 700));
    Boy panel = new Boy();

    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

            }

                  }
```

Boy class:

```
          import javax.swing.*;
          import java.awt.*;
          import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

        public class Boy extends JPanel {

JLabel boy1;
ImageIcon boy; 

          public Boy () {
setLayout(null);
setBackground (Color.white);

boy = new ImageIcon ("U:\\My Documents\\Eclipse\\JumpyBoy\\src\\TheBoy.png");           
boy1 = new JLabel (boy, SwingConstants.CENTER); 
boy1.setBounds (80, 30, 130, 500);

add (boy1);

       }
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {                     
    }}}
```

Rock class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class rock extends JPanel {

JLabel rock1;
ImageIcon rock;

public rock () {
    setLayout(null);
    setBackground (Color.white);

    rock = new ImageIcon ("U:\\My Documents\\Eclipse\\JumpyBoy\\src\\rock.jpg");        
    rock1 = new JLabel (rock, SwingConstants.CENTER);       
    rock1.setBounds (300, 240, 130, 500);


    add (rock1);
    }
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
        }}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You never add a new rock object to anything anywhere, so it makes sense that it will play no roll in your program.

While I agree that you could do well with Rock (note that all class names should begin with an upper case letter) logical class, I don't think that it's in your best interest to have it extend JPanel. Same for your Boy class. There should be a single JPanel here that holds the Rock and Boy objects and draws them.